# Sum over multiple indices that take specific values

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

Pretty simple question: how do I sum over multiple indices that can only take specific values all together?

To clarify: let's say I have the following sum:

$\sum p_{a,b,c} f(a,b,c)$

where $f$ is a function and $p$ is a coefficient (number) still in symbolic form, both dependent on indices $a,b,c$.  Here {$a$, $b$, $c$} can take values specified by a list of three numbers, like {1,2,3}, {3,6,7} and so on. My idea is that I have a list of triplets, and I would like the sum to run on these triplets by assigning $a$ to the first number, $b$ to the second and $c$ to the third. So let's say that for a list of triplets

`list={{1,2,3},{3,6,7},{2,6,9}}`

The outcome should be

$p_{1,2,3}f[1,2,3]+p_{2,6,9}f[2,6,9]+p_{3,6,7}f[3,6,7]$

I was able to do it with `Apply` if there was only a function, but the coefficients $p$ need to carry the indices so it becomes tricky.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by `p_{1,2,3}` as that translates to `{p_,2 p_, 3 p_}`.  But if `p_` is really a function that takes a list as an argument, then you might want to try `Sum[p[list[[i]]] f[list[[i, 1]], list[[i, 2]], list[[i, 3]]], {i, Length[list]}]` which gets you `f[1, 2, 3] p[{1, 2, 3}] + f[2, 6, 9] p[{2, 6, 9}] + f[3, 6, 7] p[{3, 6, 7}]`.

Comment: So $p$ is actually also a function of $a,b,c$?

Comment: no, $p$ carries indices $a,b,c$ but they are just labels. i edited the question.

Comment: So $p$ is symbolic and not numerical?

Comment: If p is subscripted (and using subscripts can have definite but sometimes unexpected consequences), then the following might be what you want:  `Sum[Subscript[p, list[[i, 1]], list[[i, 2]], list[[i, 3]]] f[list[[i, 1]], list[[i, 2]], list[[i, 3]]], {i, Length[list]}]` with output `f[1, 2, 3] Subscript[p, 1, 2, 3] + f[2, 6, 9] Subscript[p, 2, 6, 9] + f[3, 6, 7] Subscript[p, 3, 6, 7]`.

Comment: yes, i think that should do it. I will post another comment if I get stuck but thanks!

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. the p's are symbolic and in the end I need to solve a bunch of equations in order to find them. sorry, that was unclear

Comment: Can you give us an example how you specify `p`? In other words if `t` is a triplet how do I find `p[t]`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
Total[Subscript[p, #] & /@ lst f @@@ lst]
```

or

```
Total[Subscript[p, #] & /@ lst f /@ lst]
```

But you're probably making a mistake defining your p's this way, especially if you later need to do something with them. If you are willing to define p as a function, then

```
Total[p @@@ lst f @@@ lst]
```

would work.

Comment: `(p @@@ lst).(f @@@ lst)` will also work.